# How do I handle errors when a row does not exist, using better-sqlite3?

Tags: node.js, better-sqlite3

how do I handle the error that happens whenever you try to use .prepare(#).get() and the query does not exist?

```
let businessType = DB.prepare(`SELECT businessType from 'Profiles' WHERE userId = '${author.id}'`).get().businessType;
```

so basically how do I stop crashes whenever "businessType" does not exist and rather than the script crashing I can just send a message like "User does not exist" or something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` will return `undefined` if the row doesn't exist.

You will need to check your response before trying to extract the data.

```js
const row = DB.prepare(`SELECT businessType from 'Profiles' WHERE userId = ?`).get(author.id);
if(row) {
  // profile recorded exist
  ...
} else {
  // profile doesn't exist.
  ...
}
```